# Updating ArcGIS Online data from SQL Table

Tags: arcgis-online, query-layer, operations-dashboard

I am attempting to build an Operations Dashboard in our ArcGIS Online account using data from a SQL Server database. I’ve successfully added the data from SQL to ArcMap using the New Query tool, and published it to my AGOL account as a service. However, the data now on AGOL is static, it represents the data at the time I published it. The SQL database is constantly being updated (911 calls). Is it possible to get the data on my AGOL account to automatically update to represent the most current data stored in the SQL table?

*Note: the organization does not have an ArcGIS Server.

Comment: Have you tried using a view of your data?

Answer (score 2):

you will need to use [ArcGIS for Server](http://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/get-started/linux/what-is-arcgis-for-server-.htm), to host dynamic data inside a ArcGIS Online Web Map .Then use the services rest end point in your AGOL web map.

Alternatively you can write a python script to update (overwrite) the web feature service at a set schedule using your ArcMap layers.